# ¿Qué archivos se necesitan para hacer un instalador de un proyecto de java con maven?

Tags: java, maven, launch4j

he creado mi proyecto de java con maven el cuál resumidamente lo que hace es insertar una imagen (que se encuentra en adentro de la unas subcarpetas de la carpeta "resources") en un archivo .xlsx y después de la inserción agrega una fila y finalmente lo graba con el nombre del path original [sobreescribir]

```
InputStream imageStream = Documento.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/imgs/" + idLogo + ".png");
```

En fin ya he finalizado y en el archivo .pom del proyecto he agregado lo siguiente:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.gbl.paquete.Principal</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>    
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

ya compile y empaquete el proyecto también utilice la aplicación de launch4j para crear el .exe del programa, de igual manera cree un instalador que contenga las carpetas con las imagenes y todo marcha bien.
Al final ya obtuve el instalador solo que en cuando estoy en otra máquina luego de instalar el programa al ejecutarlo no muestra la imagen pero si se agregó la fila.

La ruta donde se encuentran las imagenes es: `C:\Users\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\prueba\src\main\resources\com\imgs`

Y esta es una representación jerárquica del contenido del proyecto

```
prueba
    src
        main
            java
                com
                    aux
                        auxiliar
                            GUI.java
                            Principal.java
                            ...
                            ...
            resources
                com
                    imgs
                        img1.png
                        img2.png
                        img3.png
                        logo.ico
```

¿Estoy apuntando mal a la imagen?

Comment: Es difícil saber si estas apuntando mal a la imagen si no podemos ver la estructura de carpetas ¿Podrías mostrar una imagen o árbol ascii con la estructura? También puedes asegurarte antes de utilizar "launch4j" si con solo generar el JAR ejecutable lo muestra o no, ya que de no mostrarlo puedes ver si lanza un error al ejecutar desde una terminal "java -jar myapp.jar" quizás eso te de mas pistas.

Comment: No me salen errores cuando ejecuto el JAR desde el terminal.

Comment: Aparentemente está todo correcto, pero prueba esto: un fichero jar no es más que un zip (puedes renombrar la extensión de jar a zip, si te parece más sencillo), por lo que podrías descomprimirlo y comprobar si las imágenes están correctamente añadidas. Maven copia lo que hay en resources en la raíz del archivo jar, deberías tener las imágenes en com/imgs